# prometheus jmx_exporter in kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, prometheus, ignite, jmx-exporter

Im using kubenetes and I have  a pod contain ignite db I added to the  pod another container - sscaling/jmx-prometheus-exporter:latest
I read in git I should run this

To run as a javaagent download the jar and run:

```
 java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=8080:config.yaml -jar yourJar.jar
```

but I didnt understand,  should I also download the file for the kubenrtes container as well?
can someone assist how can I continue from here

I have the following default configuration:

```
---
hostPort: localhost:5555
username:
password:

rules:
- pattern: ".*"
```

Comment: You should definitely download this JAR to your K8S container, and you can add this parameter to `JVM_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I should add this to JVM_OPTS: "java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=8080:config.yaml", not sure I understand?

Comment: You don't need to add `java` to `JVM_OPTS` :)

Comment: so I add ths to jvm_opsts -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=8080, and how can I copy during chart deployment the jar to specific container?

Comment: Just add a Docker step which will download this JAR somewhere. Seems easy.